# Append a column with LONG_RAW datatype - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a column of long raw datatype and later append the value. Is it possible? I have tried || already but not working.

```
    Update acert SET atrt= 'ddddd'

    update acert SET atrt = atrt || 'updated value'
```

Error :

> ORA-00932- expected char got binary

I want something like above work.

Also, I cannot use any DDL queries to temporarily alter the table. Is there any other way I could do this?

Comment: The long data type is used for storing information that needs to be moved from one system to another.  Why don't you use  `CLOB`

Comment: `long raw` has been deprecated over 15 years ago

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate a LONG RAW you pretty much need an external interface (C, Java, etc).

There is not anything natively in SQL or PLSQL that will do it, hence the preference to use CLOB and BLOB.